# JS: How to prevent the default action on images in browsers?

Tags: javascript

In IE, for example, when you press the left button on an image and keeping it pressed try to move the mouse, the drag n' drop action is taking place; how could I prevent this default action so that doing that way nothing will happen. I am building an image cropper, so you should understand why I need that. I am not much interested in knowing how to do so with help of jQuery or the like. As I study JavaScript, I prefer coding in plain-vanilla JS. It is important for me to learn how to make it cross-browser if there are any differences for such a thing.

Comment: respect: _do_ learn about browser headackes/hacks!  But you'll save yourself a lot of time using the tested knowledge of others about that -i.e. javascript frameworks.

Comment: Time is not that actual for me. =)

Comment: And somewhere the 'others' must have got their knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Just like August's, but plain JS:

```
var imgs = document.getElementById("my_container")
                   .getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].onmousedown = function () {
        return false;
    };
}
```

If you want to do it 'new-style', google for 'addEventListener()' (all browsers but...) and 'attachEvent()' (...IE) methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in jQuery:

```
$("#my_container img").mousedown(function () {
  return false;
});
```

http://www.google.com/search?q=cross+browser+event+hooking will probably teach you everything you need to know about cross browser event hooking. I don't know how to hook events without a framework, because that's an edge case IMHO. In The Real World (tm), you'll always use a framework.

The core here is that you have to stop the `mousedown` event from running. This will make drag and drop impossible, if you hook the event on text you won't be able to select that text, and so on.

Comment: Whoa, wait a minute. He explicitly said vanilla JS.

Comment: Which is why I pointed out that the concept is the same regardless of framework. Bitch.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building an image cropper, you're going to put some kind of overlay on the image, probably a relatively or absolutely positioned div, inside of which you will "draw" a rectangle when the user clicks, holds and drags. This will make it impossible for the user to drag the image itself, so no fix for that is needed.

Even if you do not use an overlay, you are still going to hook the mousedown event - there is no other way to implement a JS cropper as far as I know. Hooking that event will by itself be enough to prevent the browser from initiating a drag and drop action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using code similar to the following to prevent dragging, which has the advantage of targetting actual drag-related events rather than the generic `mousedown` (which could conceivably have side-effects). Works in all the mainstream browsers except Opera.

```
function cancellingEventHandler(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.preventDefault) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    } else if (typeof evt.returnValue !== "undefined") {
        evt.returnValue = false;
    }
    return false;
}

function disableDragging(node) {
    node.ondragstart = cancellingEventHandler;
    node.ondraggesture = cancellingEventHandler;
}

disableDragging( document.getElementById("anImage") );
```

Comment: ondraggesture is for Firefox 2; it's debatable whether it'll still be worth including for much longer. Unfortunately Opera responds to neither dragstart nor draggesture... I don't know of a way to stop drags in Opera other than onmousedown.

Comment: Good point, I didn't check in Opera. I didn't see the need to say explicitly that draggesture was for Firefox 2 but maybe I should've done.